# SSIS: Fuzzy lookup with dynamic configuration

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created SSIS package for fuzzy lookup.

[image]

I just want to know how to make each following properties dynamic passed to execute package for any database table's column.

1. OLEDB_Source - Server, Database,Table and Column name.
2. FL_Large_Data - Server, Database,Table and Column name.
3. FL_Large_Data - Similarity threshold.
4. OLE DB Destination - Server, Database and Table name.

Comment: As @Yahfoufi indicates, you're asking how do I make all the internals of an SSIS package dynamic and that's not a feature of the product. The column metadata cannot change during execution - only at design time. You can change source/target names but the column names, their types, etc *must* remain consistent across runs

Comment: @MAK i don't think you will get an answer other than the one you received. Yahfoufi's answer + billinkc comments are 100% true

Answer (score 0):

Since you are aiming to use this package for different tables and columns *(Maybe you can if you have a fixed and unified table structure)*, it cannot be achieved using expressions. You must automate the package creation in order to do that, you have many choices:

1. Use [BIML](http://bimlscript.com/) *(Business Intelligence Markup Language )*
2. Use [SQL Server DTS libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/creating-a-package-programmatically?view=sql-server-2017)
3. Use some Wrapper libraries such as [EzApi](https://www.kapacity.dk/ezapi-a-c-library-for-creating-ssis-packages-programatically/?lang=en)

For each one of the choices above, there are many tutorials found online, you can refer to them in order to create the package.